# Ionic Native Media plugin file status (Ionic 2)

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Ionic Native Media plugin documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/mediaplugin/) says it has some static members and instance member like **status**.

Any example on media plugin file status would help.

I tried this  ,

```
console.log(this.file.status);
```

returns  **{"_isScalar":false}**

```
this.file.status.then((status)=>{
          console.log('status 2 :' + status)
        });
```

returns **this.file.status.then is not a function**

```
this.file.status.subscribe((status)=>{
          console.log('status 3 :' + status)
        });
```

subscribe **doesn't log anything**

How do i get the file status ? and also how can static members be used to get file status ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.media = new MediaPlugin(path, (status) => {
  this.status = status;
});
```